# New field added to model - Now active_admin working locally, but not in production (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, activeadmin

I added a new field `car_color` to my Car model, and I logged in to `active_admin` locally and I see the new column on my Cars page, I can add the car's color when I edit the record, and I can set the color when I create a new one. Additionally, I was able to import a CSV with a header `car_color` using `active_admin_import`. This all worked as expected.

I updated my controller to permit `car_color` and I updated `admin/car.rb` to permit `car_color` as well.

I pushed the changes to Heroku and migrated the database using `heroku run rake db:migrate`, which looks like it worked.

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.7812
Migrating to AddCarColorToCar (20150915191640)
== 20150915191640 AddCarColorToCar: migrating =================================
-- add_column(:cars, :car_color, :string)
   -> 0.0016s
== 20150915191640 AddCarColorToCar: migrated (0.0017s) ========================
```

However, when I try to do anything with `active_admin` in production, it's as if the `car_color` field does not exist. There is no `car_color` column in the table, it is not there when I try to create a new car or edit an existing car, and trying to import a CSV with the header `car_color` throws this error:

```
undefined method `car_color=' for #<Car:0x007fcaa5e51ad8>
```

Also, when I do `heroku run console`, I am able to view and set the `car_color` on a Car with no problem, so it seems like the issue is with `active_admin`, not with the migration. Additionally, running `heroku pg:psql` and looking at the `cars` table shows the new `car_color` field there.

Any idea why this would work perfectly in development but not in production?

Comment: always run `heroku restart -a app_name` after migrations.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko, thanks, will this affect anyone using the app at the time?

Comment: In theory it shouldn't :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can happen if you or someone starts the app by a request to http://your-app.heroku.com, before you migrated the database. Whats happen is app caches the old database state without `car_color`. You need to restart your app, then it should work.